# GroupBy in List of items using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-method-syntax

I have a list that contains item like below:

[image]

Now I want to group according to language index (`Languages[x]`) like below:

**Group-1:**
model.Languages[0].Employer 
model.Languages[0].Title

**Group-2:**
model.Languages[1].Employer
model.Languages[1].Title

Can AnyBody tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Please, do not post code as images. You can use `where` clause with index

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Actually I wanted to show my generated list with code, that's why I pest the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex to extract the key:

```
var grouped = languages.GroupBy(l => Regex.Match(l, @"Languages\[\d+\]").Value);
```

Comment: I definitely prefer your answer over mine. I really need to learn Regex!

Comment: @Oyyou yes, I put it off for a while, but couldn't cope without it now.

Comment: Good one! Maybe the expression should be `"model.Languages[@"model.Language\[\d+\]"`.

Comment: @FelipeOriani that's an inavlid expression. Do you mean `@"model.Languages\[\d+\]"`? That would work as well, but the `model.` prefix is unnecessary, and the OP asked to group on the `Languages[x]` part.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe your values will be consistent, you can try the below:

```
var groupedLanguages = languages.GroupBy(c => c.Substring(0, c.LastIndexOf('.')));
```

That will group by: "model.Languages[xx]"